# Unable to find libxlutil.so.1.0 on linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, xen

I am modifying the linux kernel to  run the xen-4.2.1. and my linux is v3.4.5. After the installation of linux and xen, I executed the following command:

```
xen list
```

which gives me the following error:

```
xl: error while loading shared libraries: libxlutil.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Charles0429 locate the library . usually the library will reside in /usr/lib64. Make a symbolic link to the following folder /usr/lib....:)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem when installing xen 4.3 on Fedora 18. When configuring I figured out that: `./configure --libdir=/usr/lib` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

The file `libxlutil.so.1.0` wasn't found in the default search path. This error usually pops up if you forgot to install a dependency package.

In **Debian/Ubuntu**:

```
$ sudo apt-get install xen-utils-4.2
```

In **Redhat**:

```
$ sudo yum install xen-libs-4.2.1
```

In some circumstances, the file won't be found since it is located in a different path, or has a different name. For these cases, you can typically execute a `find` to locate the file, and then create a symbolic link with `ln` to satisfy the program.

For example, suppose there is a name mismatch and the actual file is simply `libxlutil.so` with no trailing numbers. All we need is to create a symbolic link in the same directory:

```
$ sudo ln -s libxlutil.so.1.0 libxlutil.so
```

So when the program tries to load `libxlutil.so.1.0`, it'll be redirected to the correct `libxlutil.so`.

Comment: sorry dude.. i resolved it in that there is misconfiguration when installing xen..

Comment: @Cooldharma06 could you please share how did you solve the problem? thank you!

Comment: @Charles0429 locate the library . usually the library will reside in /usr/lib64. Make a symbolic link to the following folder /usr/lib.